# Providing someone with SSH Access to server

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I possibly have a very basic question on the topic of SSH Access.

I have a trusted developer who will need SSH Access to my server, my question is what's the process of giving him this SSH access.

Forgive my ignorance but is this something I can complete through cpanel or is the process a little more involved?

A step by step would be fantastic.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide complete access to him for your server, Simply provide the root log in credentials. Normally the ssh port will be 22. You can use this link to ssh from windows machine [ssh from windows](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1595/Using+SSH+in+PuTTY+%28Windows%29#gs)

To ssh from linux machine, It is more simple. Try from terminal

```
ssh root@IP_address
password :
```

That is all you need :)